# Angular beforeunload API-Call using fetch

Tags: angular, fetch, onbeforeunload

I have a component in Angular 15 that when the window or tab is closed requires an API call to my backend. I tried to solve it like bellow, but apparently this is not a good solution, as using fetch will not guarantee that the call is successfully finished. What can I do to make sure, the window is only closed when my API call finished? (Hopefully with success but in error case it should still close the window then.)

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    if (this.sll_ID && this.auth.getUser().id) {
      const headerDict = {
        'Authorization': this.auth.getAuthToken()
      }

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('id', JSON.stringify(this.sll_ID))
      formData.append('locked', JSON.stringify(0))
      formData.append('locked_by', JSON.stringify(this.auth.getUser().id))

      fetch(environment.apiUrl + "/api/sllorderlock/", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headerDict,
        body: formData,
        keepalive: true,
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

working with the beforeunload event to make an API call before the window or tab closes is a bit complicated since you can never be sure that the request will complete before the page loads.

The beforeunload event is just allows you to show a confirmation dialog, and browsers typically do not wait for asynchronous operations to be done.

A way to come up with a solution to this problem is to make synchronous API calls, but always keep in mind that synchronous requests are generally discouraged as they can freeze the UI and provide a bad experience for users.